# DOM not updating position of a DIV inside a draggable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a lot of DIVs inside a single DIV that I'm dragging around which also moves all the other DIVs. All positions are absolute.

My problem is that after I drag around and then try to get coordinates of the inside DIV with this code: `prviLeftNotranji = $("#"+"s"+xLow+"i"+yLow).position().left;` the inside div position is not updated like the DIV I dragged around is.

**It's like the nested DIVs position's are not being updated in the DOM tree. Any idea why that is?**

This is a very general question within some very complex code so hopefuly you might better understand the question if I show you what I'm trying to achieve: http://asgarnian.com/dev/draggable.html

That thing is already finished and working but because moving all the DIVs around (setting coordinates for each of them every mouse move) is very laggy in Firefox. I decided to put all the DIVs inside a single DIV and then only move that one DIV. I have a limited amount of the inside DIVs that have to be shifted around when they hit edge of the screen to create a feeling of infinite amount of DIVs you can drag around infinitely. So because the DOM positions of one of the nested DIV doesn't update correctly my shifting code doesn't work anymore and as you can see here: http://asgarnian.com/dev/draggable3.html

If you drag right it will be shifting blocks correctly untill you release the mouse and try dragging again(since at start the position is still correct but after dragging it's not anymore.)

I don't expect anyone to understand the messy complex code I have in those two websites that's why I'm asking this like a very general question...

Comment: try with [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Ehhh I figured that the problem was that I have absolute DIVs inside absolute DIV -> which means that nested DIVs absolute coordinate is relative to their parent while I wanted it to be relative to the viewport/body. @GiacomoCosimato that actually helped me get accurate coordinates relative to screen but when I was setting the position it was still setting it relative to the parent DIV and thus making my "shifting" code all wrong. Back to recoding!... :D